# .html file automatically created on my server when user logs in

Tags: php, authentication, automation

How to make a login system (probably php) that links the information to a certain file and saves it on my server.

For example:

1. Users register with the name John Doe
2. Automatically a file JohnDoe.html is created and stored in a certain folder on my host (the file also has to contain code).
3. Everytime John Doe logs in he is being referred to JohnDoe.html, where this customer can enjoy the services that is provided to him on JohnDoe.html.

The most similar code I could find is a php code that creates a file on my server when somebody clicks the preview button. When click the preview button a preview of a html file is created on the server with a random number i.e. www.mywebsite.com/preview123213.html

This is the code:

```
    <?php

function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}


$filename = "elements/preview_".generateRandomString(20).".html";

$previewFile = fopen($filename, "w");

fwrite($previewFile, stripcslashes($_POST['page']));

fclose($previewFile);

header('Location: '.$filename);


    ?>
```

Instead of pushing preview button and creating random number, I need the code that enables users to login with John Doe and automatically JohnDoe.html is created.

Comment: `I need the code that enables users to login with John Doe and automatically JohnDoe.html is created.` You need to show your attempts at this, not the copy paste of other code. We're here to help identify bugs that perhaps you haven't seen, not do the work for you.

Comment: also, you don't create a whole new file for every user. you maybe create a user.php and passthe user's id to it so you can have it show whatever info you want that user to see.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I understand, no need to do the work for me, maybe right directions will help. I'm more focussed on design, so I really don't know where to start with the code for this, except what I already show

Answer (score 0):

I would start by creating four files "register.php", "registersubmit.php", "login.php", "loginsubmit.php".
In the "register.php" file create a basic entry form ex(textbox for username and password). Then have the form submit POST to "registersubmit.php" which will take the username and password and 
insert them into a database or data file and create a new file with the name of the given username ex(JohnDoe.html).
Then create a basic login form in "login.php" ex(textbox for username and password) then have the form submit POST to "loginsubmit.php". which will take the username and password and match them with your database and if the information is correct it will return a cookie and redirect you to "username.html". Depending on how secure you
want the page you can add cookies to the "johndoe.html" file during file creation in "registersubmit.php" to 
inhibit others from just navigating to the webpage with out signing in first. I hope this helps.